# Make Windows 7 forget non-default wifi

Tags: windows-7, wifi-configuration

Is it possible to setup Widows 7 on a labtop, so that a non-priveleged account **forgets** all wireless networks when not connected? (-but still remember one specific network.)

**Specifics:**

- There are only two accounts on the Windows 7 laptops
- I have the administrator account
- The users are using one common non-privileged account
- The users should be able to use any network(if they know the credentials)
- My workplace network should be the only one in *the network connection list* at all times
- If not connected to any other network, the computer should automatically try the workplace network
- The computer should thereby never automatically try any other network

Is this possible?

Comment: There is a very simple way to make it so that profiles are per user, not sure about making the networks "forgotten" otherwise though...

Comment: @Dupree3: Maybe my question was not clear. I have made some edits. I do not know what you mean by "...so that profiles are per user".

Comment: try this, start>run>regedit intro  then folow this path HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles and delete all unwanted profiles.

Answer (score 3):

> The users are using one common non-privileged account

This is very bad. One user may connect network, lock computer and go away. Next user may unlock it and use her network.

Addition: You may use Mandatory Profiles to reset all user settings on logoff: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx

Or you may add logout script that deletes all wlan profiles and ask all users to logoff.

Read more about network profiles.
http://www.7tutorials.com/how-delete-forget-wireless-network-profiles-windows-81

Use following command to delete profiles

```
 netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*
```

You may create `bat` file and add it as *logoff* script via local group policy.

Read more about logoff scripts: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753583.aspx

> My workplace network should be the only one in the network connection list at all times

Disable SSID beaconing (also called "hide network"). Your WIFI Access Point should support it.

> If not connected to any other network, the computer should automatically try the workplace network

Connect to it automatically on user logon. Because you delete all profiles on logoff, you may need to create one on logon. Create user logon script with

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME
```

User will be able to use connected network, or connect to another one.

> The computer should thereby never automatically try any other network

It will not, because all network profiles are removed.

PS: I really, really do not like idea of several users sharing same account!

Comment: Thank you - I will look into it. I agree, it is a huge pain to let several users share account. Problems range from sabotaging the look of the desktop to reading other peoples emails bacause of lingering sessions. My workplace boss has decided, that this is the way it is. I have no say in that matter.

Comment: Have you tried Mandatory User Profiles? windows resets them each time user loggs off: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know that network profiles are kept in the registry in :

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures
```

You could at logoff of the other users delete these keys and re-import
them from when the only network was the workplace one, using the [reg command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in a [Logoff script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753404.aspx).

As Logoff scripts are run as User, not Administrator, their rights are limited accordingly, so you will need to use the [psexec command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).
Be careful, as this means that your admin password is stored in the script
as plain-text.

I have not tested my above ideas (hacks).
Be careful and create first a system restore point,
and also use regedit to export these registry branches as backup.
Try first deleting and importing these keys via regedit,
to test the above procedure, before investing time in creating the Logoff script.